# when will google chrome support version 1.1 of the remote debugging protocol?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome version 34.0.1847.116m on Desktop windows and trying to use the [debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) inside a chrome extension.

I have successfully been using requiredVersion="1.0" and using the version "1.0" of the protocol, but want to use the "1.1" version of the protocol.

on this page related to the [protocol](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol), it states :

```
As of Google Chrome M31, we commit to supporting the version 1.1 of the protocol.
All subsequent 1.* versions of the protocol are going to be
backwards compatible with 1.1.
```

When trying requiredVersion="1.1" with chrome 34 I get the following error :

```
Requested protocol version is not supported: 1.1.
```

Is there something I am missing ? has "1.1" support never been reached for M31 ? is there an ETA on this version of the protocol ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maintainer of the feature here.

If you want to use protocol version "1.1" you can go ahead and do it. Chromium does NOT hide protocol methods specific to 1.1 if you requested 1.0, I can see how this can be confusing.

The fact that Chromium currently does not accept "1.1" as the protocol version in the`chrome.debugger.attach` call is a bug.

Thanks for pointing this out, I am fixing it now.

Comment: Could you link to the crbug or CL so that we know when the fix lands in Chrome?

Comment: @RobW, Vlad. Weird, [the doc  holds 0.1](http://archive.is/fGkYl#selection-3675.39-3675.42). But trying 0.1 would throw an error.